Matrix representation of Möbius transformation from unit disc to upper half plane.
The task is as follows:

Verify that the Möbius transformation $ z \mapsto \frac{iz + i}{-z + 1} $ from the disc model of
the hyperbolic plane to the upper half-plane model may be defined by an element of
$\operatorname{SU}(2)$.

To me this makes no sense because I would identify this map with
$
\begin{pmatrix}
i & i\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
which is not in $\operatorname{SU}(2)$.
How am I supposed to approach this exercise?

the simplest looking matrices for this are in one direction, $ \frac{iz+1}{z+i}$  and the other direction  $ \frac{z+i}{iz+1}$  which is also the reciprocal of the fraction. I don't remember which is which, but the second one takes $0$ to $i,$   disc to half plane.  The first one is half plane to disc. Alright, given REAL x  show $| \frac{ix+1}{x+i} | = 1$   which uses the fact that, real $x,$   that $\bbar{x+i} = x-i$

so $|x+i| = |x-i|$   for real $x$

Is some scalar multiple of that matrix an element of $SU(2)$?

Oh my god. I didn't even think about that. Thank you so much for that hint!!
